# how do i add headers and page numbers in the footers

Tags: ms-word

I am trying to use word 365 to format a book for printing.

to add different headers on odd and even pages, (design) (options) (different odd and even) has to be checked.

to add page numbers in the footers, (design) (options) (different odd and even) has to be unchecked.

? how do I add page numbers in the footers without messing up the headers?

jerry

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions; end-user questions should be addressed to SuperUser or the Microsoft Answers forum. But for what it's woth: Different Odd/Even must be in-force for the entire document - there's no turning it off or selecting where it applies. But you should certainly be able to add page numbers to the footer with the option activated! When you ask in a more appropriate place you need to explain why you feel it doens't work with different odd/even activated.

Comment: thanks, Cindy .. I have been a computer programmer since 1959 .. 59 years .. an old timer .. I am trying to finish a math book for people who want or need to learn a little more math .. to get standard headers added I have to turn (design) (options) (different odd and even) on .. but with it on i can't get the footer page numbers to work .. I have already done a lot of internet searching for a solution .. a call would be greatly appreciated .. you can find my contact info by searching for (wa0h), (0) is the number zero .. anything that comes up will link to my website .. jerry .. age 77.

Answer (score 0):

You do no have to uncheck odd & even pages to have page #s in the footers. Simply create your odd & even page setup, add the odd & even header content to the headers and, likewise, add the page # fields to both the odd footers *and* the even footers.